# <ul> Menu won't center

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I have a menu on wordpress that I'm trying to center, but it wont center itself. If I put auto on margin it doesn't do anything but when a fixed number is set, it does, but it doesn't align perfectly unlike using auto.

CSS

```
.menu {
    width:auto;
    float: left;
    display:block;
}

#navcontainer {
    display:inline;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px; /*-8px 0 0 10px;*/
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    float:left;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<section class="twelve columns text-center" style="background: transparent;">
<div class="menuimg">
<img src="http://fabioide.com/frederiksminde/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/menu.jpg">
</div>
<div id="navcontainer">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => false, 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?></div>
</section>
```

Comment: http://fabioide.com/frederiksminde/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI now replace `two css` in your style sheet

```
#navcontainer {
float: none;
display: block;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
height: 20px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

.menu {
width: auto;
float: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your css and your ul menu set center of #navcontainer with margin auto

change css as per follow:

```
.menu {
  width: auto;
  float: none; /*set this to float:none*/
  display: inline-block; /*set this to display:inline-block*/
  margin-left: auto;
}
#navcontainer ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 0px; 
  overflow: hidden; /*add this to your css*/
}

#navcontainer ul li a{
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: the css for menu work.
whats for the overflow for #navcontainer ul

Comment: you set your li to float:left so you do not clear your float in ul so just give ul to overflow:hidden it clear your float

Comment: #navcontainer ul li a this border stop shake on hover to li menu

Comment: overflow:hidden makes the top border of the menu disappear when hovered though...

Comment: #navcontainer ul li a in this css add display:block and your top border will appear. @MichaelPon

Comment: it work but the submenu's left border then disappear some of them... i think i need to add overflow;visible to the children class

Comment: i see your site i did not see any submenu border make disappear can you describe ?

Comment: @MichaelPon Always Welcome